# Changing column separation in smallmatrix environment

Tags: math-mode, matrices

How can I change the width of the space between columns in a smallmatrix environment? I can't find any decent documentation on smallmatrix anywhere.

The array environment has the setcolsep{..} command, but I can't find anything analogous for smallmatrix.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The intercolumn space is `\thickspace`; you can do a trick

```
\newenvironment{xsmallmatrix}[1]
  {\renewcommand\thickspace{\kern#1}\smallmatrix}
  {\endsmallmatrix}
```

Now you can decide for yourself what the separation is (default .2777em):

```
\begin{xsmallmatrix}{.5em}
a & b\\
c & d
\end{smallmatrix}
```

If you want a fixed different space, say .5em, define

```
\newenvironment{xsmallmatrix}
  {\renewcommand\thickspace{\kern.5em}\smallmatrix}
  {\endsmallmatrix}
```

Beware that `\thickspace` is used in other places and it might happen in one of the small matrix entries (not very probable, though). A more robust patch might be

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\patchcmd{\smallmatrix}{\thickspace}{\kern.5em}{}{}
```

and from now on all `smallmatrix` environments will use .5em as intercolumn space.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a small document, which shows a redefinition of `smallmatrix` fur supporting an optional argument for the separation. The definition is taken from `amsmath.sty`, it's just extended by using this argument instead of `\thickspace`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\makeatletter
\renewenvironment{smallmatrix}[1][.2777em]{\null\,\vcenter\bgroup
  \Let@\restore@math@cr\default@tag
  \baselineskip6\ex@ \lineskip1.5\ex@ \lineskiplimit\lineskip
  \ialign\bgroup\hfil$\m@th\scriptstyle##$\hfil&&\kern#1\hfil
  $\m@th\scriptstyle##$\hfil\crcr
}{%
  \crcr\egroup\egroup\,%
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\[
  \begin{smallmatrix}
    a & b\\
    c & d
  \end{smallmatrix}
  \quad
  \begin{smallmatrix}[8pt]
    a & b\\
    c & d
  \end{smallmatrix}
\]
\end{document}
```

It's using internal macros as the original definition does, which might be changed. While egreg shows a workaround and a patch, this should show a straighforward redefinition starting from the original source code.

Comment: However it's not so easy for somebody not expert in `\halign` and plain TeX syntax to spot the right place to act on.

Comment: It's not better, just showing another way for quick fixing: locating the original macro, redefining, spotting the place (yes, hard here), changing. Perhaps motivation to read the source, showing that also enormous complicated code can be re-used easily.